# Quantified logic: is my answer equivalent to the other solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I'm reviewing for an exam, and I'm having trouble with a practice problem.

Translate the following into quantified logic: There is a student who sells cookies and another student with straight A's whenever all students are home for winter break.

Let C(x) = "x sells cookies", A(x) = "x has straight A's", and W(x) = "x is from for winter break".

The solution given to me is: $\forall x(W(x) \rightarrow \exists y \exists z(C(y) \land A(z)))$

I think I see how that is correct, but I came up with a different answer and was wondering if it is equivalent to that solution.

My solution: $\forall x(W(x) \rightarrow (\exists y C(y) \ \land \ \exists z A(z)))$

Would my solution be correct too?

Comment: So after staring at my solution for a minute, would it be incorrect because I didn't state that y does not equal z?

Comment: The sentence is confusing.  "There is a student that sells cookies whenever all the students are home for the winter break and another student with straight A's." is sensible.

Comment: I believe it is trying to say whenever all students are home for winter break, there is a student who sells cookies, and another student who has straight A’s. Sorry if it’s confusing, but that sentence was copied word for word from an old exam.

Comment: Yes, $\exists y\exists z(C(y)\land A(z))$ is logically equivalent to $\exists yC(y)\land\exists zA(z).$

Comment: If $P$ is a formula containing no free occurrences of the variable $z,$ then $\exists z(P\land A(z))$ is logically equivalent to $P\land\exists z A(z).$

Comment: So $\exists z(C(y)\land A(z))$ is logically equivalent to $C(y)\land\exists zA(z),$ etc.

Comment: What you reported as the solution given to you has unbalanced parentheses.  Could you check it? ("Your solution" has the same problem.)

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the given sentence.  $S$ has the form "$P$ whenever $Q$," where $P$ is

$$\exists y \exists z (C(y) \wedge A(z) \wedge y \neq z)$$

and $Q$ is $\forall x\, W(x)$.  Combining $P$ and $Q$ into $Q \rightarrow P$, we get

$$(\forall x \, W(x)) \rightarrow \exists y \, \exists z \, (C(y) \wedge A(z) \wedge y \neq z) \enspace.$$

Putting this sentence in [prenex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form), we get

$$ \exists x\, \exists y\, \exists z \,(W(x) \rightarrow (C(y) \wedge A(z) \wedge y \neq z)) \enspace. $$

Let's translate it back into English: there are three students, $x$, $y$, $z$, the last two distinct, such that either $x$ is not home for winter break, or $y$ sells cookies and $z$ has straight A's.  We can make this sentence true by exhibiting a student who's not home for the break, because then we are under no obligation to show two more students to satisfy the consequent of the implication; or we can make the sentence true by exhibiting two distinct students, one selling cookies and the other having straight A's, because then the fact that all students are home for the break is of no concern.

Compare the sentence above to

$$ \forall x\, \exists y\, \exists z \,(W(x) \rightarrow (C(y) \wedge A(z) \wedge y \neq z)) \enspace. $$

This sentence is false if at least one student is home for the break, but no student sells cookies (or no student has straight A's, or the only student with straight A's is also the only one to sell cookies).  As far as I can tell, that's not what $S$ claims.